# Dynamic Javascript Map Merge

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a way to dynamically merge maps. I am new to maps in javascript but have seen merging maps by using dot notation. I am looking for a way to dynamically add maps to an array and then generate a new map based off the values of the array.

*This is what I have seen and used.*

```
let map1=map2=map3=new Map();
map1.set(0, 'foo');
map1.set(1, 'foo');
map1.set(2, 'foo');
map1.set(3, 'foo');

//var map2 = new Map();
map2.set(1, 'foo2');
map2.set(2, 'foo2');

//var map3 = new Map();
map3.set(3, 'foo3');
let merge = new Map([...map1, ...map2, ...map3]);
```

*I am looking for something like this though.*

```
//returns a map of maps data  Map(key: time, value: Map(key:id, value: Object))
let dataStore = getData(); 
let mapStore = [];
let merge;

for(i=value; i>=0; i--){
  if(dataStore.has(i)){
      //push map into the mapstore array
      mapStore.push(dataStore.get(i))
      //key object in map to notate that a full update should be performed. 
      if(dataStore.get(i).has(updateFlag)){
          //merge mapStore maps into new map
          merge = new Map(mapStore); //results in map with undefined key and value              
          break;
      }      
  }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. please provide a bit more details of your expected input and output.

Comment: "This is what I have seen and used" `let map1=map2=map3=new Map();` I really, really hope not. That's copying references to the *same* map. Unless that's what you want. Also, are you sure you need a `Map` here? Why not POJOs?

Comment: Was just a quick initialization. My maps in my use case are all generated dynamically and provided by a data service. was just showing the dot notation used for merging the maps.

Comment: You say you get maps from a datastore, but I'm very, very surprised that your datastore is returning ES 2015 Maps. Again, are you sure you should be using Maps instead of JavaScript objects? What are you really trying to accomplish here? It isn't really clear from the question. Please edit more detail into the question itself.

Comment: ES6 Maps need to have key/values set somewhere.

Comment: I understand that. I may have simplified the code too much. Basically I am getting a large map of maps ordered by 2 sets of keys. So dataStore in this example is an ES6 Map with a key value pair of [key: time, value: map [key: id, value: Object]] So they are already instantiated. I am trying to pull out maps matching my criteria and merge them into one map.

Comment: @ZacharyEvans yeah I think you did. Happens, NBD. Post a (small) example of your existing data from the datastore, and then what you want it transformed into. That's probably enough for us to work with.

Comment: @JaredSmith, unfortunately I am not able to post any of my src. But I can try to create something similar.

Comment: Your question is still rather unclear. You want to merge maps with overlapping keys? What happens if there's a conflict (same key in multiple maps)? Last write wins? Accumulate them in an array? What's the updateFlag thing? Please post *data*, what goes in, **what you want to come out**. It doesn't have to be *real* data, but it has to be in the correct structure (and preferably with the actual types, do you really have integer keys?). I still have no idea what you want other than a vague description of "merged maps".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

was able to merge the maps using this:

```
let merge = new Map([arrayOfMaps])
```

Comment: This doesn't work, does it? It creates a map with one entry: `undefined => undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that you could do something like this and make use of the forEach in Map(). You will obviously need rules for handling cases where the same key exists in map1 and map2. Does that mean replace, or only include ones that previously didn't exist as in below:

```
let mapStore=new Map();
let map1=new Map();
map1.set(0, 'foo');
map1.set(1, 'foo');
map1.set(2, 'foo');
map1.set(3, 'foo');

let map2 = new Map();
map2.set(1, 'foo2');
map2.set(2, 'foo2');

let map3 = new Map();
map3.set(3, 'foo3');

map1.forEach(function(value, key)){
  if !mapStore.has(key){
     mapStore.set(key, value);
  }
}
map2.forEach(function(value, key)){
  if !mapStore.has(key){
     mapStore.set(key, value);
  }
}
map3.forEach(function(value, key)){
  if !mapStore.has(key){
     mapStore.set(key, value);
  }
}
```